# Visual Studio C++ Project Subsystem Console Causes COM Port Open to Return ERROR_

Tags: c

I have a rather simple serial communication project created in Visual C++ Express 2008 using C only. It opens a com port, writes some packets to an embedded device, closes the com port. Since I do have some printf() statements in the code and I'd like to watch those messages while the code is running, I go to Properties->Linker->System->SubSystem and change the option to "Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)". This allows me to run a Debug session with a console window open and see all the printf() messages coming out. However, when I try to run the .exe file (instead of a Debug session), the code would only work ONCE. The second time, I always get INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE on com open, i.e., CreateFile(...) call, and GetLastError() returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE (0x6). It seems that I am missing some proper procedures at the end of my program. 
My com open looks like this:

```
    fComOpenPort = CreateFile(
    ComPort, 
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
    0, 
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, 
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
    NULL
    );
```

And this is how I close the com port along with TX and RX threads.

```
    if (hComRxThread != NULL)
{
    CloseHandle(hComRxThread);
    hComRxThread = NULL;
}

if (hComTxThread != NULL)
{
    CloseHandle(hComTxThread);
    hComTxThread = NULL;
}

if (fComOpenPort != NULL && fComOpenPort != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    PurgeComm(fComOpenPort, PURGE_RXABORT | PURGE_RXCLEAR | PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR);
    CloseHandle(fComOpenPort);
    fComOpenPort = NULL;
}
```

If I change the SubSystem back to "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)", I can run the .exe any number of times, no problem at all, but I don't get any printf() messages.

Comment: Probably you have the process not killed somewhere on background with this port open.

Comment: Anyway to find out which process?